# Having trouble with an aviation-band receiver

Tags: antenna, schematics, receiver, high-pass-filter

I finished assembling an aviation band receiver that I bought online. I thought it would be good project for my resume, as I am an electrical engineer major at a University in California. I read the schematic properly and soldered everything on to the PCB board.

Unfortunately, I cannot hear any sound. I can't figure out if it is maybe the components or the circuit board it self. Or maybe I need a different antenna.

I am very confused and really wish I could get this to work.

What kind of formulas or theories do I need to use in order to start from scratch in making my own schematic? Do I need to incorporate a high-pass filter?

Here is the schematic of what they sent:

[image]

Here is the completed PCB:

[image]

Comment: Does it at least hiss at you?  You should hear at least a little background noise.

Comment: All those resistors where you had a hard time putting them were intended to be mounted vertically.  That is, they are supposed to be standing instead of laying.  That probably doesn't have anything to do with your problem - unless one of the squeezed in parts is causing a short somewhere.

Comment: @JRE, no it doesn't. I know it is supposed to make some noise, and that's why I posted my question because I can't even get it to make any type of noise.

Comment: 1.  Check that U6 has about 12V on pin 6. 2.  Check that the 78L08 has 12V on pin 3 and 8V on pin 1.

Comment: @JRE I realized that after I soldered them all in that they were intended to be mounted vertically. My fault, learning. However, I noticed that the germanium diodes were different. One was bigger than the other. I wonder if that has something to do with it. On the schematic it doesn't specify where they should go.

Comment: I see on the internet that there are two different housings for that diode, and that it makes no difference.  Even if there were a mix up, that would only prevent it from receiving.  You should still hear at least a little hiss from the audio amplifier U6 (the LM386.)

Comment: @JRE - interesting. I checked them both and I get no voltage. I wonder if it might be my power supply?

Comment: Check that you have D3 installed correctly and that your power supply has 12V on the center pin and ground on the barrel (the outside.)

Comment: @JRE okay I'll check D3. Also I am using a 12V 500mA power adapter.

Comment: @JRE still no voltage, D3 polarity was correct

Comment: @JRE - Getting a new board and starting over. I have a feeling your hypothesis is right. I think I may have caused a short some where with the resistors and possibly the diodes. Thanks for your help. I'll  keep you updated if you're curious.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite - I think it is good practice to know how to put a circuit board together and trouble shoot things and learn the parts. At my university they don't do hands on like this. I rather would've liked to design my own schematic and design my own aviation band receiver but I don't know where to start. My senior design project is not a aviation band receiver, and are classes are all online so it is pretty difficult to ask my professors for help to design something of this magnitude. Do you have any suggestions on alternatives?

Comment: I agree that designing something this complicated would be very ambitious for a student and I also agree that one can learn some skills from doing it. My point was that it is not resume enhancing since it involves no design or analysis and, apparently, not much methodical  troubleshooting. I'm sorry you are in an EE program with no labs.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite We do have labs. But they are not this complicated, and not as hands-on. We use breadboards vs using actually printed circuit boards. We don't solder and I am sure if my university doesn't do it other schools for sure *DO NOT*.

Comment: As far as the theory you are learning, there is nothing wrong with  breadboards although they will not be very effective for higher frequency projects. For image of undergraduate soldering on a printed circuit board see https://edgerton.mit.edu/courses/electronics-project-laboratory-6070j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @JRE mentioned, I shorted the resistors by putting them on horizontally. I needed to put them vertically on the board. By doing that I was able to get the circuit working. [image]